# Error 1040 mysql en MacOs

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

Hola tengo el siguiente error después de instalar  MySql con brew en MacOs Ventura (Macbook pro m1):

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).
```

Segui las instrucciones que aparecieron al finalizar la instalacion:

```
MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -u root
```

Intenté seguir un tutorial que implicaba correr este comando:

```
sudo mysql

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_new_password';
```

Pero tampoco me deja acceder al clt de mysql, me vuelve a salir el mismo error de acceso denegado.

Esto es lo que muestra la terminal despues de terminar la instalacion:

```
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -u root

To restart mysql after an upgrade:
  brew services restart mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.31: 315 files, 297MB
==> Running `brew cleanup mysql`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
==> Caveats
==> mysql
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -u root

To restart mysql after an upgrade:
  brew services restart mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql
```

No hay configurada ninguna contraseña, aun asi no puedo usar el comando mysql -u root. Si ejecuto el comando mysql_secure_installation, me sale esto:

robertramirez@Roberts-MacBook-Pro ~ % mysql_secure_installation

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
```

Creo que es para crear la nueva contraseña, pero me da el error cuando se la doy

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Intenta con: `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Me pide una contraseña, pero no tengo ninguna contraseña configurada, es justo despues de la instalacion, introduzco cualquier palabra y me sale el mismo error.

Comment: Entonces ¿no has ejecutado `mysql_secure_installation`?

Comment: Si, pero me pide esto: 'Enter password for user root: ', creo que es para crear una contraseña, pero la ingreso y me sale de nuevo el error.

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta toda la sesión (entrada y salida) de `mysql_secure_installation`, no es claro en qué punto del programa aparece el error.

Comment: Listo, agregué mas información